# Number of possible Feynman diagrams at a given perturbative order

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, interactions

In perturbative quantum field theory, all amplitudes for processes $\sum \text{in}\to \sum \text{out}$ involving particles that interact according to a certain interaction Lagrangian $\mathcal L_I$ are calculated perturbatively by expanding the $\mathbb S$-matrix, so that $$a=\langle \text{out}|\mathbb T\exp\left(i\int d^4x \mathcal L_I\right)|\text{in}\rangle=\langle \text{out}|\mathbb T\exp\left(\mathbb I+iS_I+\frac{i^2}{2!}S_I^2+...\right)|\text{in}\rangle. $$ This can be done explicitly by writing down all possible contractions between the creation/annihilation operators $(a_i, a_i^\dagger)$ contained in the input/output states and the fields $\phi_i$ contained in $\mathcal L_I$, as well as between the fields $\phi_i$ themselves, according to combinatorical principles or, formally, by Wick's theorem.

The final amplitude $a$ is a sum of many terms, and each term can be associated to a Feynman diagram, which as I understand are built as follows:

- for each involved particle there is an *external* vertex of degree $1$ (with *degree* I mean the number of edges, or lines that connect a vertex to the others) that can only be linked to *internal* vertices, with an edge labelled by the momentum $p_i$ of the particle;
- at the $n$-th perturbative order there are $n$ internal vertices, which are linked to both internal or external vertices, of degree $k$, where $k$ is the number of fields in $\mathcal L_I$;
- at each internal vertex the law of conservation of momentum must be satisfied.

Equivalently, one can start the computation by writing down the Feynman diagram and according to specific rules that depend on $\mathcal L_I$ evaluate the associated analytic expression.

---

My question is: given the triplet $\left(\mathcal L_I,\sum \text{in}\to \sum \text{out}, n\right)$ and taking into account all 'duplicate' diagrams obtainable from one other by symmetry, can one determine the number of all possible diagrams? Is this number independent from the form of $\mathcal L_I$, but dependent only from the number of fields it contains?

Comment: [This paper](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.18.1939) may be relevant.

Comment: [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.04517) is a more recent one.

Comment: "at the n-th perturbative order there are n internal vertices" Do you mean with vertices internal interaction field lines (say three virtual photon lines in the case of third-order electron-electron interaction)?

Comment: I believed that this has been solved (take the muon, for example, they have computed up to FIVE loops!). All needed is a definitive reference.